# 2015 Macbook Air Can't connect to WiFi (BCM4360)

Tags: wifi

Is there a guide for getting this working offline? Every guide I've found has come up short for me, and I have no way to connect to ethernet. Bluetooth tethering doesn't work either. I can connect to my p

Comment: I've got the same problem. On my MacBook Pro Retina, no wifi drivers or even settings were installed despite checking the box for third-party drivers.